# Curvature and arc length

Tags: calculus

> Given $r(t) = (t,\cosh(t),0)$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Compute the arclength function and verify that it is unit speed, that is $|r'(s)| = 1$

Basically since cosh(t) is symmetric about $x = 0$, I used the arclength function

$$s = \int_{0}^{t}2|r'(t)| dt =2\sinh(t) $$

So $t = \log \left (  \dfrac{s + \sqrt{s^2 + 4}}{2} \right )$. I save you all the trouble from doing the horrible algebra, but in the very end, one gets

$r'(s) = (1/(s^2 + 4),s/(2\sqrt{s^2 + 4})$ and clearly $|r'(s)| = 1/2 \neq 1 $

I am guessing something went wrong from the very start. Perhaps my symmetry argument was flawed?

**EDIT** I was given $r(t)$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$. So I wasn't told what is the starting point to integrate. How do I know that I should let $t_0 = 0$?

Comment: How did you get $2\sinh(t)$? Isn't $r'(t)=(1,\sinh(t),0)$?

Comment: I took the magnitude of $|r'(t)|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the $2$ came from, or why you need any symmetry arguments: the arc length $s(t)$ of a curve $\gamma(t)$ is simply $\int_0^t \|\gamma'(u)\|\,du$ and so, as you've calculated, $s(t) = \sinh(t)$.

Also, notice that you don't need too much nasty algebra to confirm that $r(s)$ is unit speed:
$$\frac{dr}{ds} = \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dt}}=(1, \sinh t, 0) \frac{1}{\cosh t}.$$

Comment: Going from $0$ to $t$ gives half of the branch of the curve. The other half is given by the $2$

Comment: What branch? $s(t)$ measures the arc length of the (single-valued) curve $r(u)$ from $u=0$ to $u=t$.

Comment: But your s(t) only gives half of the arc length no? Feels like I am asking something completely different...

Comment: It sounds like you're measuring the arc length of the curve from $u=-t$ to $u=t$. To unit-speed reparameterize the curve you want to measure the arc length from a *fixed* point (say, 0) to $t$.

Comment: But why choose $0$? Why not say $t = 4$?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. You'll just get a more complicated $s$.

Comment: What about $t = -4$? My book James Stewart defines the arclength function as $s(t) = \int_{a}^{t} |r'(t)| dt$ where $r(t)$ is defined $a \leq t \leq b$. Here it suggests I let $a = \infty$

Comment: Infinity is a bad idea, since $\lim_{a\to\infty} \sinh(a) = \infty$.

Comment: that's what I mean. I can't use infinity even though it is suggestingt hat i use infinity

Comment: Just use 0. Or 4. Or any finite number will work.

Comment: But the curve was given to be $-\infty < t < \infty$. My arc length function should've been $$s(t) = \lim_{r \to -\infty} \int_{r}^{t} |r'(\tau)| d\tau$$

Comment: I think you're confused... there is no unique arc length parameterization function $s(t)$. It doesn't matter at all what finite $a$ you pick. All will give you the right answer. So you pick the one that's easiest to work with... in this case, $a=0$ is a good choice, since $\sinh 0=0$.